# java selenium how to use if else

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

There is a table with application numbers and user data. at the beginning of the table, the application number at the end is a green arrow. There can be an infinite number of fields in a table and it always changes.
I need to find the green arrow by the application number and click on it accordingly.

tried to do something like

```
String myorder = "629/0000/000000021059";


    if (myorder.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]\n")).getText())){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[18]/a/img\n")).click();

    }  if (myorder.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]\n")).getText())) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[18]/a/img\n")).click();

    } if (myorder.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]\n")).getText())) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[18]/a/img\n")).click();
```

and so on up to 100+
The first problem is that I really don't like the option of writing if else 100 times. And there is only one digit in the diva where the id of the application and one in the digit in the diva where the green arrow is different(img)

The second problem is that no matter how I insert break; when finding the right application, he clicks on the desired arrow, but after apparently trying to continue searching the page, but the page has already changed and the error falls

```
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

if I use the code that was attached above or just an indication of the element (which goes right after the one that turned out to be correct and the page has changed) with a note that I can not find it, if I use else if with break;

tried to do so

```
for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        String myorder = "629/6300/000000412067";

        if (myorder.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div["+ i++ +"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]\n")).getText())) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div["+ i++ +"]/table/tbody/tr/td[18]/a/img\n")).click();
            break;
        }
```

But if the item is located, then it clicks on the very first arrow in the table, and not on the one in the same column as the application number

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing, but in the loop you are doing `i++` twice. So you should replace the second `i++` with just `i` to stay consistent with the logic in the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

XPaths are 1-based not 0, so you are correct in thinking you need to add one, however, these two are not equal as `i++` modifies the value of `i` (even inline like you have it), which you do twice inside your loop. Therefore the 2nd iteration of your loop `i` will be 3, not 1 as expected. In your loop replace `i++` with `i + 1` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        String myorder = "629/3500/000000329976";

        if (myorder.equalsIgnoreCase(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + 1 + "]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]\n")).getText())) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[" + i + 1 + "]/table/tbody/tr/td[18]/a/img\n")).click();
            break;
        }
    }


Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[31]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]
```

"}

So it was searching untill 31. And it's strange because i used for i < 25 and there are only 25 rows in the table.
but still dont work for me;(